# Problems with local database when deploying web site using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, database

I've tested my site locally in visual studio and everything looks good. However when I publish my site, I'm getting an error "The database provider is not specified for this connection string ", however it works fine on my local.

I then get the error "no databases are selected to publish" on the next screen.

I've noticed that the "Release" option is missing in the configuration manager for me but my .mdf file is available in the app_data folder.

I published my site anyway, but when I call a stored procedure I get an error and my guess is that it's because my app can't find my database.

My connection string is in my web.config file.

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source=hostname\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password"/>
```

Comment: Can you share the connection string? Where you are publishing the sited? On the local machine or on some other server?

Comment: Added my connection string. Im publishing on the local server, which is also where my SQL server is running